# How do I stop the Edit Quicklinks taking me to Advanced settings n Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

My problem is that when I click on the Edit link under the Quick Links in my Sharepoint site, it takes me to Advanced Settings -> Site Nagivation.

[image]

It used to just allow me to click on a + symbol so I could add a new quicklink on the side like the following image.

[image]

I would like to be able to go back to the modern way of doing it, but not sure whether it is a setting that has changed. I looked at [Sharepoint: editing site navigation goes to advanced settings](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharepoint-editing-site-navigation-goes-to/cd8eca6d-a313-44a7-8fa4-06ca2a013b08) but that feature was not activated.

Has anyone come across this issue before and fixed it?

Regards,
Darren

Answer (score -1):

Per your description, I would like to confirm whether clicking on the Edit in the Site Navigation will take you to the Navigation Settings page? If yes, it seems you activated the Site Collection Feature called **SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features** in the SharePoint Online Site. You can go to the Site Settings> Site Collection Features, to confirm whether the feature is activated or not.

If yes, you can try to deactivate the feature and check the result.

Comment: Vote begging has been removed from your answers at least five times now, and this is becoming a drain on volunteer labour. Please refrain from adding it again.